# Rails app on Heroku: HTTP and HTTPS not working simultaneously with Firefox client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, ssl, heroku, https

I have a Rails 4.0 e-commerce app that enforces HTTPS on the checkout page, while enforcing HTTP on other pages (due to unavailability of 3rd party HTTPS libraries). I'm deploying on the Heroku cedar stack at a custom domain, and after I've accessed the HTTPS page once using Firefox, all future HTTP requests get converted to HTTPS.

As a result, by application gets stuck in an infinite loop of redirects (my app detects HTTPS request and redirects to HTTP, and firefox keeps sending back an HTTPS request). I don't get this problem with other browsers- Chrome and Safari.

On searching online I found-
- It's a Firefox 'bug'. If browser history contains HTTPS communication with the domain, then it enforces HTTPS on all future requests.
- A possible solution was to configure a .htaccess file, but I'm not sure of how to do that on Heroku, and whether that would work with Nginx or if that's only for Apache. Solutions details are here- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/933563

Is there a solution to this problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

To redirect from HTTPS to HTTP, I have a before_filter in a Controller:
*
before_filter do
  if request.protocol == "https://"
    redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently
  end
end
*

To force HTTPS on checkout page, I use:
*
force_ssl
*

Comment: I'm having the same problem but in reverse ( trying to redirect http --> https ). If you are using Heroku's "pass through" SSL, it does not seem to be compatible with many of the traditional methods of detecting SSL, such as .htaccess `%{https}` or some PHP's $_SERVER values.